How to add a firebase-messaging-sw.js file to Bubble [EDIT - file not recognized]
I know that in a common resolution to the error below, I need to add a firebase-messaging-sw.js file. Since I'm using a bubble HTML element to run the script, I'm not sure how to do that. I tried using a CDN, but I'm not sure I did it properly, or if there is a better way. What do you think?
Here's the error:
An error occurred while retrieving token.  FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The document is in an invalid state. (messaging/failed-service-worker-registration).
    at registerDefaultSw (registerDefaultSw.ts:43:25)
    at async updateSwReg (updateSwReg.ts:28:5)
    at async getToken$1 (getToken.ts:43:3)


An error occurred while retrieving token.  FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The document is in an invalid state. (messaging/failed-service-worker-registration).

Here's how I tried to add the file:
<script type="importmap">
{
    "imports": {
        "firebase/app": "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.9/firebase-app.js",
        "firebase/messaging" :"https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.9/firebase-messaging.js"
    }
}
</script>
  <script type="module">
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getMessaging,getToken } from "firebase/messaging";
const firebaseConfig = {
//my config
}
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const messaging = getMessaging(app);

const swUrl = 'https://3b4293b7c2497062d0307b62bd49f75f.cdn.bubble.io/f1720473376600x761326990998907800/firebase-messaging-sw.js';
const sw = document.createElement('script');
sw.src = swUrl;
document.head.appendChild(sw);

getToken(messaging, {vapidKey: '...myactualvapidkey...'}).then((currentToken) => {
  if (currentToken) {
    console.log(currentToken);
  } else {
    console.log('No registration token available. Request permission to generate one.');
  }
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
});
</script>

Note that the service worker file is currently empty, because according to this tutorial, it should work with an empty file.
I also tried the answer from this similar question, but it didn't work for me. I got an import issue when trying to use the 'firebase/messaging/sw' package.

EDIT
I've discovered that it is possible to add a file to root (at the way end of Settings-->SEO/metatags) , but the file doesn't seem to be recognized. I've tried the following to get the service worker to be recognized:
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/firebase-messaging-sw.js').then(function(registration) {
      console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
    }, function(err) {
      console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
    });
  });
}

but I get this error:

ServiceWorker registration failed:  DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The document is in an invalid state.

Note that this code is being rendered from an iFrame and that the file firebase-messaging-sw.js is empty.

"I tried using a CDN, but I'm not sure I did it properly, or if there is a better way. What do you think?". You should edit the question to explain exactly what you did do.  We can't tell if you did it right because we don't know what you did.  Please include all the steps you took so that we can reproduce the same result exactly as you did it.

@DougStevenson I did include the steps at the bottom of the question.

You didn't describe "how".  You described its contents.  We don't know where you put it or how that file gets served or deployed for actual use.  We don't have the specific steps to reproduce.

@DougStevenson you're right. See edits. (In my actual implementation, I did make an attempt to serve that file using the register command, but it didn't work, so I figured I was way off base and left it out.)

The second error shows a CORS violation and has nothing to do with Firebase.  A web app can only directly load URLs from the same site where the HTML came from.  I suggest sticking to the error that seems to be related only to Firebase, and focus on how you are building the project so that someone can reproduce it.  I still don't know how your project is composed, tested, or deployed and wouldn't be able to reproduce what you've done there without specific steps.

@DougStevenson ok, so I'll explain more clearly. I don't exactly have a project to deploy; everything is within a bubble.io HTML element. There are no files in the project or directory structure; there's just the script I posted, pasted entirely within a basic html element. https://manual.bubble.io/help-guides/design/elements/visual-elements#html

@DougStevenson a bubble html element literally just contains the html with the associated script; I wish I could be more descriptive, but if we rephrase the question as: "assuming that I needed to add a service worker and the config is set up correctly, how would I add the service worker file without placing it in the directory?"

@EthanLeonard Firebase v9.6.9 released in March 2022. The latest version is v10.12.3 (in July 2024). Do you see the same problem when using the new version? Do you have a demo page where your element renders? Is it attached to the page nested in an IFRAME tag or is it inline?

@samthecodingman Thank you for telling me that! Unfortunately, yes, I see the same problem with the new version. The element does render correctly on the page, and the error shown in the console is under User Messages and under Info, but not under the errors tab. (Since I have an exposed config inside it, I can't share that page here.) It is in an IFrame.

@EthanLeonard I've been tinkering around and discovered that while in preview mode, any custom root files (like /firebase-messaging-sw.js) are nested in the /version-test folder like the rest of the app. So your service worker would need to be conditionally registered using const serviceWorkerRegistration = await window.navigator.serviceWorker.register((location.pathname.startsWith("/version-test") ? "/version-test" : "") + "/firebase-messaging-sw.js", { scope: "/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope" }); getToken(messaging, { vapidKey: "...", serviceWorkerRegistration }).then(...);

Note: This answer is a work in progress and/or incomplete. I am sharing what I have in case it helps someone else investigating this.

<script type="module">
  (async function () {
    // note: targetting Firebase Web SDK v10.12.3
    // note: using direct import() syntax just for testing
    const { initializeApp } = await import("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.12.3/firebase-app.js");
    const { getMessaging, getToken } = await import("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.12.3/firebase-messaging.js");

    const firebaseConfig = {
      // my config
    }

    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const messaging = getMessaging(app);

    const serviceWorkerRegistration = await window.navigator.serviceWorker.register(
      (location.pathname.startsWith("/version-test") ? "/version-test" : "") + "/firebase-messaging-sw.js",
      {
        scope: "/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope"
      }
    );

    // note: deleted lines where service worker was attached as a script

    try {
      const currentToken = await getToken(messaging, {
        vapidKey: "<VAPID_KEY>",
        serviceWorkerRegistration
      });

      if (currentToken) {
        console.log(currentToken);
      } else {
        console.warn('No registration token available. Request permission to generate one.');
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
    }
  })()
    .catch(err => console.error("An unexpected error occurred.", err));
</script>

Note: "/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope" is the default scope value used by the SDK

Unfortunately, I still get the same error. But I'd like to understand this a little bit better. How does the default scope affect the setup? Does the firebase-messaging-sw.js file need to be put in the default scope? (I don't know how to do that, because the most I can see that bubble has in the way of a directory is the root folder, but should that be goal?) What else can I try?
